# Restoring backup file with Postgresql pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

How can i restore a file generated by the command:

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -F c -b  -f bkp_file.backup "alfa"
```

I tried to use 
   psql -U user -d alfa-f bkp_file.backup

But i got tons of errors regarding invalid characters. so i'm not sure if i'm doing the pg_dump correctly.

An exemple of the error output:

```
psql:cmdb_21-11-2012.backup:1399: invalid command \3?6IÅñå|J‼▼§↓OTaIEDóP&5¶◄▲Ct±^ºO-²
psql:cmdb_21-11-2012.backup:1400: invalid command \ÖÿYÇ/µèI=ÜdUEàmß¿ê÷E|>I▬ßf♂*»Å?B/÷
IYñAªóS`Wö3ßAÆ?l*ádECIY‼)á¢'ul#`aåAArZæp2_í_ÉY-ëU&>ïIìO·▼$5
```

In fact, theres a lot of those characters on the dumped backup file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i created the backup using the pg_dump command described on the question. also, im updating the question with the error output. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dumping a compressed form of the data and restoring it using a program expecting the uncompressed form. Either remove the *-F c* from your pg_dump line or use [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: Thank you, i forgot about that =)